# Confused on whether to use local or remote port forwarding?

Tags: networking

I would like to access the internet from my laptop, but using the connection provided by another machine. I have an ssh login for that machine but I'm not sure if I am looking for remote or local port forwarding. I am still partially confused about the difference between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want dynamic port forwarding. E.g.,

`ssh -D 12345 host.example.com`

(On PuTTY, configure the dynamic forwarding port under `Connection | SSH | Tunnels`.)

Then you configure your browser to use port 12345 (or whatever port you chose) of `localhost` as a SOCKS 5 proxy. This will tell your browser to send its connection requests to the `ssh` client listening on port 12345 of your local machine, which will in turn forward those requests to the `sshd` on `host.example.com`, which will execute the connection requests as appropriate and return the data along the reverse path back to your browser.